# Fetch API - Targeting an Iframe

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, forms, fetch-api

Using the **target** attribute of an html form, you can post form data and then have the html-server-response showcased in an iframe.

```
form.setAttribute("target", "nameOfIframe");
```

Can the same thing be achieved posting with the ecmascript fetch api (without creating an actual html form element)?

Comment: Are you asking if `fetch` can update the contents of an IFRAME? or whether you can use fetch in a larger function to update the contents of on IFRAME?

Comment: Sure, it can. What's holding you back from trying it out? If you have a specific question on a specific part of your fetch code, feel free to ask it.

Comment: @phuzi I'm interested in what ever works. The goal is to get a fetch result into an iframe, in that same manner that a form submission result can target an iframe.

Comment: @shaedrich : I don't know how to send a fetch response to an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the fetch POST response into the iframe by using the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) property of the iframe, as advised to me by this [AI answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIUuY.png).

```js
async function sendFetchResponseToIframe()
{
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('input1', 'value1');
  formData.append('input2', 'value2');
  
  let options = {};
  options.method = 'POST';
  options.mode = 'cors';
  options.body = formData;
  
  let postURL = 'http://neartalk.com/test/formData.php';

  let response = await fetch(postURL, options);
  let data = await response.text();

  let iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
  iframe.srcdoc = data;
  
}
sendFetchResponseToIframe();
```

```html
<p>The fieldset below contains an iframe that gets updated to the Fetch POST response:</p>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Iframe</legend>
  <iframe id="frame1" style="width:100%" src="http://www.example.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</fieldset>
```

However, this method is not as transparent as setting the target of an HTML form, which preserves all relative links that may be returned by a server's HTML response.

While there are methods of addressing this, like: (1) Modifying the html response to include a [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element, or (2) modifying the HTML response to convert all relative links to absolute links. I can still imagine other complications like server-side redirects that could ultimately occur. Such redirects would lead to you ultimately having to also modifying your fetch code to follow the redirects, determine the final URL, and convert the base URL or absolute links accordingly.

Due to these complications, the answer to my question is ultimately: No; you're better off creating a hidden HTML form dynamically, and setting its target prior to submission, and then ultimately removing that dynamically created form after submission. This method more easily protects the relative links that could potentially be in the HTML response:

```js
function submitFormToIframe(actionURL, formData, iframe)
{
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = actionURL;
  form.method = 'POST';
  form.target = iframe.name;
  for (const [name, value] of formData.entries())
  {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = name;
    input.value = value;
    form.appendChild(input);
  }
  form.style.display = "none";
  document.body.append(form);
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);
}

async function main()
{
  // Create Form Data:
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('input1', 'value1');
  formData.append('input2', 'value2');
  
  // Get iframe from DOM:
  let iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
  
  let actionURL = 'http://neartalk.com/test/formData.php';
  submitFormToIframe(actionURL, formData, iframe);  
}
onload = main;
```

```html
<p>The fieldset below contains an iframe that gets updated via generated form submission:</p>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Iframe</legend>
  <iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" style="width:100%" src="http://www.example.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</fieldset>
```

Due to these findings, I think the specification writers, should consider adding a fetch option that allows you to send a fetch response directly to a specified iframe, in a manner where relative links aren't susceptible to breakage (as is the case with [HTMLFormElement.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/target). This would make the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) a more attractive solution.

Comment: I updated my question, well before any answers occurred. Since that update included AI advise, a moderator removed it. I never posted the AI advise as an answer. In this answer I do post a link to the AI answer that initially inspired my first solution. Yet ultimately, I came up with my own solution, which is included. I'm all for not providing AI as an answer on stackoverflow, but pretending that AI doesn't exist, and not giving it credit when its due, seems disingenuous to me.

Comment: submitting the temporary hidden form is brilliant! This has the additional added benefit of solving my CORS problem with fetch, since the iFrame src is on another domain.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly trivial to update the content of an IFRAME with JavaScript/EcmaScript and can be done using the [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) property.

```js
document.getElementById('fetchTarget').srcdoc = `<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello World!</p>`;
```

```html
<iframe id="fetchTarget">
</iframe>
```

All you would need to do is arrange to update it as part of the processing of the call to `fetch`:

```js
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok){
      return response.text();
    }
  })
  .then(text => {
    document.getElementById('fetchTarget').srcdoc = text;  
  });
```

```html
<iframe id="fetchTarget">
</iframe>
```

This URL isn't a particularly great example as it returns JSON instead of HTML but it doesn't really affect the result.

Comment: This will break any relative URLs in the HTML, so it's not very useful for arbitrary documents.

Comment: @Quentin : That's a good point. Is there any way around that? The nice thing about the HTML form [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/target) method, I mentioned in my question, is that it doesn't break any relative links provided by the server's response.

Comment: @Quentin : That issue can be addressed, to a degree, by modifying the server's response to include a [base](https://i.imgur.com/2wij0No.png) element.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process the data inside the iframe, you can use [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Instead of [`iframe.srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) property, you can of course put the code in a separate file and reference it via [`iframe.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-src)

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let otherBtn = document.getElementById('btn2')
let wrongBtn = document.getElementById('btn3')
let results = document.getElementById('results')
function showResults(json) {
 results.contentWindow.postMessage({
  action: 'showResults',
  data: json,
}, "*");
}
function sendForm() {
  fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(showResults)
}
function addLinkToIframe() {
  results.contentWindow.postMessage({
    action: 'addLink',
    data: {
      href: 'index.html',
      text: 'Click me!',
    },
  }, "*");
}
function addCallNonExistentAction() {
  results.contentWindow.postMessage({
    action: 'gibberish',
    data: 'even more gibberish',
  }, "*");
}
btn.addEventListener('click', sendForm)
otherBtn.addEventListener('click', addLinkToIframe)
wrongBtn.addEventListener('click', addCallNonExistentAction)

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.action === 'iframe::DOMContentLoaded') {
        console.log('iframe loaded');
        results.contentWindow.postMessage({
          action: 'setBase',
          data: document.baseURI,
        }, "*");
      } else {
        alert(`Action '${event.data.action}' not defined`)
      }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Send</button>
<button id="btn2">Add link</button>
<button id="btn3">Call non-existent action</button>
<hr />
<iframe id="results" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href=>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.action === 'showResults') {
        document.body.querySelector('pre').appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(event.data.data, true, '\t'))
        );
      } else if (event.data.action === 'setBase') {
        console.log('setbase')
        document.head.querySelector('base').href = event.data.data
        console.log(document.baseURI)
      } else if (event.data.action === 'addLink') {
        link = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
          href: event.data.data.href,
        })
        link.textContent = event.data.data.text
        console.log('add', link)
        document.body.prepend(link);
      } else {
        alert(`Action '${event.data.action}' not defined`)
      }
    })
    window.parent.postMessage({
      action: 'iframe::DOMContentLoaded',
    }, '*')
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Waiting ...
  <pre></pre>
</body>
</html>
"></iframe>
```

Comment: Would this method preserve any relative links that might be in the server's html response?

Comment: @LonnieBest No, it wouldn't. You'd have to use the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element to achieve that.

Comment: This can also be done via postMessage. I added an example to the answer.